# Pass data to 2 controllers, 1 returns a view, 1 returns a JSON response

Tags: json, laravel-5

I'm getting data from a view.

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
    {!! Form::input('date', 'from', date('Y-m-d'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    {!! Form::input('date', 'to', date('Y-m-d'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Go', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) !!}
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Once the user submits, I have a controller that fetches the inputs and returns a view. In my ReportsController, I have:

```
public function report(Request $request)
{

    $from = \Request::input('from');
    $to = \Request::input('to');

    $resources = Resource::where('resources.created_at', '>=', $from)
        ->where('resources.created_at', '<=', $to)
        ->get();

    return view('reports.index', compact('resources'));
}
```

However, I want to use the same data inputs from the user to update a json that will be used in the reports.index view returned above. In the same controller, I want to have something like:

```
public function json(Request $request)
{

    $from = \Request::input('from');
    $to = \Request::input('to');

    $resources = Resource::where('resources.created_at', '>=', $from)
        ->where('resources.created_at', '<=', $to)
        ->get();

    return Response::json(['data'=> $resources]);
}
```

How do I make this possible? Will appreciate your help so much!

Comment: Finally thought of a solution - that is, to store the dates in a table. Not so elegant, but I get to evade learning ajax for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the json in the same view, why don't you simply pass the json to the view in the report() function?

something like this:

```
public function report(Request $request)
{
    [....]
    return view('reports.index', compact('resources'))
       ->with('json'=>Response::json(['data'=> $resources]));
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping out. I got this error when I did what you suggested: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW). Anyway, I will look for the correct syntax somewhere else. Thanks again!